# Laravel: Call to a member function getRealPath() on a non-object

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I'm creating a website for a client with a gallery for images etc.

I'm running into this error:

`ImageController Line 16: Call to a member function getRealPath() on a non-object`

`ImageController` looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Image;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ImageController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {

}

public function store(Request $request) {
    $file = $request->file('image')->getRealPath();
    $image = new Image();
    $image->title = $request->get('title');
    $image->desc = $request->get('desc');
    //$image->date = $request->get('created_at');
    $image->image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
    $image->type = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if($image->save()) {
        return redirect(route('web.home'))->with('status', 'Uploaded!');
    } else {
        return redirect(route('store.upload'))->with('status', 'Upload failed!')->withInput();
    }
}

}
```

and my form looks like this:

```
<form action="{{ url(route('store.upload')) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{!! csrf_field() !!}
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="title" name="title">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="title">Titel</label>
</div>
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
    <textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" rows="5" id="desc"></textarea>
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="desc">Beschrijving</label>
</div>
<input type="file" name="image">
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored right" type="submit">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
</button>
```

This is basically an edit of an earlier gallery I created and should (in theory) work.

Comment: can you comment everything inside function store and post result of var_dump($request->file('image')) ? ;

Comment: @NicolòCozzani `object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[29]
  private 'test' => boolean false
  private 'originalName' => string 'ClapSlide.png' (length=13)
  private 'mimeType' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
  private 'size' => int 0
  private 'error' => int 0` the entire store function has already been given

Comment: Happy that you fixed your problem, by the way there are better solution for uploading files using laravel, instead create a new image you can just move your uploaded file.

Comment: Thanks for the extra sollution, though I prefer to do it this way for now, it's not like there are gonna be a ton of images uploaded every day, the owner of this site is just gonna use it for simple small business purposes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem, I declarede one of the routes wrong, after which the error went away, I got another error, which was because I forgot to add a file type column to the table, after which I forgot to set the name for the description, so that also resulted in an error, every error is now fixed and works perfectly

Comment: Then this question is redundant; this answer is not at all useful to other users with similar problems.